# how to find next span to div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have a **div** and a **span** next to it i just want to give it **top** using jquery how can i do it. both **div** and **span** are generating dynamically. Div has id "**divTest**" i want to find next span to this div. I have tried some tricks but didnt succeed yet.

**Updated:**

Actually i have implemented the Password Strength on a page. and i want to change the position of that. I am pasting the html rendering in browser

```
    <input id="main_cntrlChangePwd_txtNewPassword" class="feild" type="password" maxlength="300" name="ctl00$main$cntrlChangePwd$txtNewPassword">
<div id="PasswordStrengthBorder" style="position: absolute; display: inline; height: 3px; top: 95px; left: 445px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; padding: 2px; width: 200px;"></div>
<div id="PasswordStrengthBar" class="BarIndicator" style="position: absolute; display: inline; height: 5px; top: 97px; left: 447px; width: 75px; background-color: blue;"></div>
<span style="position: absolute; top: 105px; left: 445px; font-size: 75%; display: inline-block;
 width: 240px;">5 more characters, At least 2 more numbers, 1 more symbol, 1 Upper case characters</span>
<br>
<span id="spNewPwd" class="imp_msg error_msg">Message</span>
</div>
```

Thats all

Comment: Use jquery selectors .children() or .next()

Comment: span is not inside the div its next to div..........

Comment: If you want more than just guesses, please post an HTML representation of your structure.

Comment: what does $('#divTest').next("span") returns ?

Comment: @FelixKling please review my question

Comment: After the update the question became extremely confusing, as the HTML contains neither a div nor a span but an input field, followed by some weird text.

Comment: `I have tried some tricks but didnt succeed yet.`  Tell us what tricks you have tried.

Answer (score 20):

Use jQuery [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$("#divTest").next("span").css("top", "10px");
```

***Live Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/YUNXa/

Comment: If certain that the span is following immediately after the div in the HTML, `.next("span")` could be just `.next()`

Answer (score 4):

like this?

```
$("#divTest").next();
```

Or you can also try

```
$('#divTest').nextAll('span:first');
```

Comment: I have already tried this but its not working

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: no not getting any error...

Answer (score 2):

May be this is what you need

`$('#divTest').next('span')`